# Spam tweets dataset needed

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, twitter

Where can I find **labelled spam tweets dataset** that has at least **50000** rows. I've searched everywhere; but there are very few datasets available, and those datasets are way too small.

I am in urgent need of one, as I will need it for my MSc dissertation, any leads are greatly appreciated.

Thanks much.

Comment: Did you check this ? - http://nsclab.org/nsclab/resources/

Comment: there is an open source data stack exchange dedicated for this kind of request.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check this ? - nsclab.org/nsclab/resources